# memory leak when reload highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Increasing memory problem occurred when reloading Highchart

I try running `chart.destroy()` explicitly on reload, additional 'chart animation : flase' but it is not a perfect way to solve the problem.

```js
setInterval ( "initChart()", 1000*30 );`        

function initChart(){

    if ( typeof $ ( '#guage1' ).highcharts () !== 'undefined' )
    {
        $ ( '#guage1' ).highcharts ().destroy ();
    }

    var data = [{
        borderColor: "red",
        color: "#7cb5ec",
        innerRadius: "100%",
        radius: "100%",
        y: 60
    }];

    setHighcharts($('#guage1'), data);
    datas($('#guage1'),data);
}


function datas($container,data){

    var chart = $container.highcharts();

    if(typeof chart !== 'undefiend' || chart != null){

        var y = null;
        y = chart.series[0].data[0].y;

        for ( var i = y; i >= 0; i = i - (y / 80) )
        {
            chart.addSeries ( {
                data : [ {
                    y : i,
                    radius : '100%',
                    innerRadius : '100%',
                } ],
                stickyTracking : false,
                enableMouseTracking : false
            }, false )
        }
        chart.redraw ();

        Highcharts.each ( chart.series, function ( s )
        {
            s.update ( {
                borderColor : s.data[0].color
            }, false );
        } );
        chart.redraw ();
    }
    chart = null;
}


function setHighcharts($container, data1) {
console.log('');

    $container.highcharts ( {
        chart : {
            type : 'solidgauge',
            spacingBottom : 0,
            spacingTop : 0,
            spacingLeft : 0,
            spacingRight : 0,
            marginTop : 28,
            marginLeft : 28,
            marginRight : 28,
            marginBottom : 28,
            backgroundColor : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)',
            style : {
                fontFamily : 'Nanum Gothic'
            },
            animation: false
        },

        title : {
            text : '',
            style : {
                display : 'none',
            }
        },

        pane : {
            startAngle : 0,
            endAngle : 360,
            background : [ { // Track for Move
                outerRadius : '112%',
                innerRadius : '88%',

                backgroundColor : 'rgba(17, 17, 26, 1)',
                borderWidth : 0
            } ]
        },

        yAxis : {
            min : 0,
            max : 100,
            lineWidth : 0,
            tickPositions : [],
            stops : [ [ 0, '#218ad8' ], [ 1, '#69ff05' ] // red
            ],
        },

        plotOptions : {
            solidgauge : {
                borderWidth : '15px',
                linecap : 'round',
                dataLabels : {
                    enabled : false
                },
                rounded: true
            }
        },
        series : [{
            data : data1,
        }]
    });
}
```

I have a page with 5 gauge chart and I reload the chart every 30 seconds and the memory size increase.

I guess the something object created is still in memory.

the first load is 159.6MB after 7 reload 171.8MB.

So, How can I free the memory on the reload?

Answer (score 0):

Destroying each chart and initializing it every 30 seconds is not a good idea. Instead, you can use methods to update the chart dynamically like: `chart.update()`, `series.addPoint()`, `series.setData()` etc.

**Demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-update/
- http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-addpoint-append/
- https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 

By the way, I am using the method to delete the html DOM that draws the chart using the empty() function and then upload the chart again. So, I think I should use the destroy() function.